# Colapse Menu após refresh da página com localStorage

Tags: jquery, html, session, cookies, localstorage

Como posso fechar um menu e o manter fechado após o *refresh* da página utilizando jQuery apenas?
Seria algo como [neste link](http://radiant-ocean-4606.herokuapp.com/index.html).

Ao clicar no botão [image: colapse] o menu é reduzido e assim permanece mesmo após o *refresh* da página. 
Ao clicar novamente no botão o menu volta ao estado original e se mantém da mesma forma quando a página é atualizada.

Como posso simular este efeito sem PHP? Ou teria que usar uma session ou um cookie?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Existem algumas maneiras que você pode fazer isso vou citar 2 que venho em mente e são métodos bem simples.

**API HTML5 LOCAL STORAGE**

Você pode acessar o objeto **localStorage** e trabalhar com seus metodos `setItem` e `getItem` exemplo:

```
localStorage.setItem("menu","visible");
localStorage.getItem("menu");
```

> [Aqui](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) você pode ver alguns exemplos da API e compartibilidade.

---

**Cookies**

Nada como nosso bom e famoso cookie.
Percebi que você esta familiarizado com jQuery então
acredito que este plugin do jQuery irá te ajudar bastante é o
jquery.cookie
Exemplo:

```
$.cookie('menu', 'visible'); //setando o valor visible para o cookie menu
$.cookie('menu') // lendo o cookie menu
```

> [Aqui](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) esta seu repositório e toda a documentação.

Caso você queira ver essas informações armazenadas no navegar abra a ferramenta do desenvolvedor no `Chrome`(Menu->Ferramentas->Ferramentas do desenvolvedor ou aperte F12) clique na guia `Resources`, lá você pode navegar em diferentes recursos de armazenamento do browser e ver as informações armazenadas **daquele domínio**.

Comment: Cara, muito bom, valeu d+. Esse HTML5 é show de bola.